# Como faço para verificar o conteúdo interno de um array?

Tags: javascript, array

Como faço para verificar o conteúdo interno de um array?

Por exemplo:

```
var teste = [1, 2, 3, -4, 0]
```

Como faço para verificar se o conteúdo interno é menor igual a 0 dentro do array?

Comment: Você precisa verificar em todas as posições? Se sim, estude o `filter` de *arrays* do JavaScript.

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta está pouco clara. Eu pensei que ele queria saber se o array tem mais de 0 elementos ("conteúdo interno do array")...

Comment: Você quer saber a soma interna do array é menor ou igual a 0 ou se existe algum valor menor igual a 0?

Comment: Desculpe pela pergunta um pouco clara, mas eu preciso verificar os itens do array e se ele for menor ou igual a zero, se esses números forem maior que 2 fazer uma ação.

Comment: Então se for `menor ou igual à 0` deve se fazer uma ação e se for  `maior que 2` deve se fazer outra?

Comment: isso, se for menor ou igual retorna true e caso ao contrario retorna false

Comment: Coloque na pergunta como você deseja que seja a saída.

Comment: "...eu preciso verificar os itens do array e se ele for menor ou igual a zero..." os erros de sintaxe e semântica sugerem uma pergunta conflituosa, a parte "eu preciso verificar os itens do array" sugere que tem que iterar e comparar os itens. A parte "se ele for menor ou igual a zero" sugere que você não precisa iterar e sim utilizar o comprimento do array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `filter()`, nesse caso ele irá percorrer o array e excluir os numero positivos, os que irá permanecer no array são apenas os negativos ou zerado.

```js
const array = [-1, 0, 1, 2];
const qntNegativos = array.filter(nr => nr <= 0).length;

console.log(`Existe(m) ${qntNegativos} numero(s) negativo(s) ou  zerado(s).`)
```

---

Referência: [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

Answer (score 0):

cara para verificar se o array retornar vazio, você pode utilizar o método `length`,
a pergunta esta pouco clara. Porem voce pode fazer o seguinte.

```
var teste = [1, 2, 3, -4, 0]
if(teste.length > 0){
console.log('O array não é vazio')}
else{
console.log('Array Vazio')
}
```